# What is url in ajax

Tags: ajax, cordova

I am developing a cross platform application using cordova. I have to send data from a form in app to a database which is on the on a local server created using XAMPP. MY .php file is in htdocs in xampp. I have tried many different things but nothing worked, the problem seems to be with ajax url. What value is given in ajax url. Now, my database is on my laptop using xampp server.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read this FAQ https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to narrow your question

Answer (score 0):

You should give webserver ip adresse and path to you'r PHP file.

Don't forget you will test from an Android or IOS apps and so there havent access to localhost.

So if you'r PHP file path is : localhost/hello.php you have to check you'r ip adress (cmd -> ipconfig) and then use this url on you'r ajax request : 192.168.XXX.XXX/hello.php